# How to combine/pipe multiple selectors?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to combine multiple css selectors in a single expression ?
  For example I would like to match the nodes that have the parent class `visit` and children class `Home` and attribute name `align`, value `left`.

`.visit > .Home` works as expected but when I add the attribute filter `[align="left"]` it fails to return any result. 
I've tried something as below but its not working. I'm new to CSS so any guidance would be helpful. I assume/expect there is a AND(&&) operator equivalent which would pipe the result from the child combinator into the attribute selector but I can't find any.

```
.visit > .Home [align="left"]
```

Comment: Remove the space before `[`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector...

```
.visit > .Home [align="left"]
```

... is saying, *select all elements with an attribute/value pair `align="left"`, that are descendants of elements with the class `Home`, that are children of elements with the class `visit`.*

Remove the space between `.Home` and `[align="left"]`.

Then the selector will read: *select all elements with the class `Home` AND an attribute/value pair `align="left"`, that are children of elements with the class `visit`.*

Comment: Thanks a lot! I find that quite brittle. Would `.visit[align="left"] > .Home`  be equivalent to my current version? (`.visit > .Home [align="left"]`)

Comment: No. They're two different selectors. Consider posting sample code. We can help you more effectively if we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Your answer solves my current problem so perhaps I should read more the CSS specs to understand how to combine multiple selectors .